# I was not told that I am on probation

Tags: discrimination, probation

I’m working for about 6 months now! I feel that I am discriminated in my work place but I cannot prove it.  This is my first full time job and I never claimed that I am superexpwrienced but so far I didn’t make any mistakes. Recently I felt my boss is not happy with me anymore and I kindly asked for a reason! He simply said I was on a probation and he MIGHT extend my probation period for three more months (till big projects end and we go to winter)! I was never told I’m on a probation neither verbally nor in my offer letter. I had other offers or interviews that I could consider instead if I knew! But I am really freaked out! My boss clearly does not appreciate my work and trys to ignore me in front of everyone! Could someone guide me what to do?

Comment: Where are you located? Are you a member of a union?

Comment: What does your contract say? If you're on probabation, it should explicitly mention the timeframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify any region/country you are working in. In most countries, I know, probation-periods have to be part of your contract. Also in many countries, the length of a probation-period is regulated by law, so your employer would not be able to extend (or even shorten) this period at his will.

So most important for you right now is, what local employment law is saying about probation-periods, as well as what your contract is saying about probation.

But even (and especially) if your supervisor is wrong about this subject, this kind of behavior would raise some red flags for me, because in this case, it would be very unprofessional and you might consider to move on anyway.

Comment: Probation might also be prescribed in a collective bargaining agreement

Answer (score 2):

As you are on probation, even though you have only just been told, that usually means that you can gracefully decline to continue working there at the end of the probation period - that is the same for both sides, they can terminate you at the end of the probation period as well.

So, decide whether you want to stay or move and sort out the cv and, perhaps, check out those other offers...

If you want to stay, make sure you work on whatever the manager has an issue with...

Now, not being told you were employed with a probation period is a concern - perhaps this was an error by the manager or HR or the interview team, it may be worth checking with HR to see.

Comment: If employers can just freely put employees on probation, wouldn't that circumvent any contract clauses and laws around notice periods and termination? Wouldn't this need to be agreed to in writing to be enforceable?

Comment: "decline to continue working there at the end of the probation period" - while it might be possible it works like this here, every probation period I've ever had, and heard of, involved a shorter notice period instead of the option to leave at the end. The option to leave at the end sounds more like contract-to-hire, which is something else entirely.

Comment: @Dukeling I was employed on a contract with a probation period of 3 months which at the end of said 3 months could be terminated by either side. I suppose you have never had that "privilege"...

Comment: that's highly depending on country and local law.

Comment: @Hilmar it is highly dependant on the words in the contract...

Comment: @SolarMike: Sure. But what can be put legally in a contract is very dependent on country. Some European countries are more protective then the US.